# C# .net core - Nested Div with ID on button press load, but works on normal load. ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a view component in my view and it works properly when its loaded one time. This view is part of a Slideshow so there are buttons on it. When the user clicks the next button it creates a duplicate outer div tag.

Now with both of these divs with the same ID my css is not working properly.

I have been trying to figure out why this is happening and been changing a lot around but I haven’t had any luck fixing it yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Fileview.cshtml
@model MesserUI.ViewModels.LNPartVM
@await Component.InvokeAsync("DataPage")

DataPage.cshtml
@model MesserUI.ViewModels.LNPartVM
<div class="mx-auto contentblock">
    <a class="carousel-control-prev"  role="button" data-slide="prev" id="btnPrev">
        <span class="bg-secondary "><i class="fas fa-arrow-left carousel-icon"></i></span>
    </a>
  <div id="part" class="text-center mx-auto row justify-content-center"  >
      <img class="img-fluid mt-2" src='@ViewData["imagePath"]' />
    </div>

</div

DataPageViewComponent.cs
public class DataPageViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DataPageViewComponent> _logger;

        public DataPageViewComponent(ILogger<DataPageViewComponent> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            if (TempData != null)
            {
                TempData.Keep();
            }

            List<LNPartVM> lstData = null;
        }
   }
```

[image: example]

After I click the next or previous button this is what I get. But on the first load I only get a single div id=part with my img inside.

Comment: ID's must be unique.  You should fix that as it will cause other problems... particularly with any javascript.

Comment: The IDs are suppose to be only 1 div. Its not 2 separate divs. The viewcomponent is duplicating itself.. that is my whole issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, I had to reformat my pages.

fileview.cshtml

```
<div class="mx-auto contentblock">
        <a class="carousel-control-prev"  role="button" data-slide="prev" id="btnPrev">
            <span class="bg-secondary "><i class="fas fa-arrow-left carousel-icon"></i></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next"  role="button" data-slide="next" id="btnNext">
            <span class="bg-secondary "><i class="fas fa-arrow-right carousel-icon"></i></span>
        </a>
        <div id="contentData" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("DataPage")    
        </div>    
    </div>
```

DataPage.cshtml

```
<div id="part" class="text-center mx-auto row justify-content-center"  >
  <img class="img-fluid mt-2" src='@ViewData["imagePath"]' />
</div>
```

DataPageViewComponent.cs

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            if (TempData != null)
            {
                TempData.Keep();
            }

            List<LNPartVM> lstData = null;
                if (lstData?.Count > 0)
                {
                    TempData["SlideTotal"] = lstData.Count;
                    LNPartVM partVM = lstData[partIndex];
                    return View("DataPage", partVM);
                }
            return View("DataPage");
        }
```